# pyspark cannot write file to local path

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm facing below error when trying to write parquet file to my local. But weird enough, when i change the path to aws s3 it got no issue generating the output. And ideas why?
Thanks so much!

code:

```
df_node.write.parquet(temp_path + 'db_type/node', mode = 'overwrite')
```

error trace:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/jovyan/work/BI/OSM/temp/db_type/node/_temporary/0/task_20211022070321_0010_m_000001/part-00001-fcb50be3-3408-4d80-b056-4597be8d4f65-c000.snappy.parquet (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileInputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:110)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.open(RawLocalFileSystem.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:367)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:292)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.rename(RawLocalFileSystem.java:373)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.rename(ChecksumFileSystem.java:614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.mergePaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.mergePaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJobInternal(FileOutputCommitter.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:364)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter.commitJob(ParquetOutputCommitter.java:48)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:187)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: add you code snippets with your question and Error Stacktrace

Comment: i was just doing a simple dataframe write parquet, with "overwrite" mode, and the error indicates: "No such file or directory"

Comment: probably you (Spark) don't have write permission on `/home/jovyan/work/BI/OSM/temp`?